# How to prevent overflow error for Row widget?

Tags: flutter

This is a simple two columns layout for desktop application. The window can be resized to any size even very small like 100x100 thus the content won't fit by design and should be clipped. And normally it's working until I use Row to build the layout

```
void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Row(
          children: [
            // left panel
            Container(
              width: 400,
              child: Placeholder(),
            ),
            // content panel
            Expanded(child: Placeholder())
          ],
        ),
      )
    );
  }
}
```

Now I'm getting an error like "A RenderFlex overflowed by 3.3 pixels on the right." if I resize the window to a very small size.
So far I've tried to use SingleChildScrollView but found it's working only for Column.  Also I've played with ClipRect but don't know how to use it for this case.

Edit: Solution with Warp widget won't help here as moving the widgets doesn't help if they just don't fit - I can resize the window so the width is less than the width of the first row cell. What's more I cannot use Expanded widget for the right cell.
Actually this is very common layout with left panel for menu and right for the content

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Flutter: How to fix overflow in row?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66088881/flutter-how-to-fix-overflow-in-row)

Comment: Actually no. I don't want to move the widgets as wrap does. I want to clip the window content if the window is too small. The workaround I found is to use window_manager package and set minimum width equals to left panel width. But I'm still interested in finding a solution

Comment: you can use singlechild scroll view just add   scrollDirection:Axis.horizontal .

Comment: @JeelBhatti it didn't work as expected

Comment: can you send the expected output image or something?

Answer (score 0):

To prevent an `Overflow` on your `Row` widget. Instead of using a `Row`, use [`Wrap`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Wrap-class.html) - which wraps the widgets to the next line when there's no space:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
        home: Scaffold(
      body: Wrap( // --> Use Wrap instead of Row
        children: [
          // left panel
          Container(
            width: 400,
            child: Placeholder(),
          ),
          // content panel
          Expanded(child: Placeholder())
        ],
      ),
    ));
  }
}
```

- Here is an [official video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=z5iw2SeFx2M) by the Flutter team, explaining `Wrap`.

Comment: Wrap cannot contain Expaned widget and I need to fill the remaing space. I'd need sth like https://github.com/flutter/flutter/pull/136161

Answer (score 0):

The SingleChildScrollView has a [scrollDirection](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/SingleChildScrollView/scrollDirection.html) property, with the default value being 'Axis.vertical'. It should work fine if you set it to 'Axis.horizontal'.

Additionally, there is a [FittedBox](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FittedBox-class.html) widget, which can adapt to changes in parent size.

Comment: It's working fine for Column but not for a Row

Answer (score 0):

I think if the layout is dynamic, why you don't try to use percentage for the widget width?

for example, base on the screen width to get the percentage value

```
 Container(
    width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.4,  //40% with screen width
    child: Placeholder(),
  ),
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of giving a static width of 400, you can make it dynamic using media query.

For example, let's say your screen width is 600 and and you want your container to have a width of 400; then, what you can do is simply calculate the width ratio (400*100)/600 = 66.67.

```
Container(
width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.66,  //This will give container the width of 66% of the screen
child: Placeholder(),),
```

Comment: That's good point, I'll use it but won't work if a user resize window to 50pxx50px

Comment: On resizing the window the build method will be called again and it will resize the container according to current width.

Answer (score 0):

As my question got negative score - not sure why - I'm posting workaround for this I think quite common problem.
I'll use https://pub.dev/packages/window_manager to enforce  minimum width of the window so the window width >= left panel width